# Simple select to optimize in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, create-table

I have the following query and I want to optimize it, the execution time is 4 seconds and the number of rows is 122,928, but the tables do not have anyone link between  them.

Is there any ways to optimize this? I need the same number of rows but the time of execution needs to get down considerably.

```
select dc.cddocument, us.cduser
from dcdocument dc, aduser us
 WHERE  (dc.FGUSECATACCESSROLE <> 1 OR dc.FGUSECATACCESSROLE IS NULL);
```

Query Plan

```
teste20=# explain analyze select dc.cddocument, us.cduser from dcdocument dc, aduser us WHERE  (dc.FGUSECATACCESSROLE <> 1 OR dc.FGUSECATACCESSROLE IS NULL);
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1584.32 rows=124110 width=8) (actual time=0.062..23.679 rows=122928 loops=1)
       ->  Seq Scan on aduser us  (cost=0.00..19.91 rows=591 width=4) (actual time=0.029..0.190 rows=591 loops=1)
       ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..13.56 rows=210 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.012 rows=208 loops=591)
             ->  Seq Scan on dcdocument dc  (cost=0.00..12.51 rows=210 width=4) (actual time=0.024..0.308 rows=208 loops=1)
                   Filter: ((fgusecataccessrole <> 1) OR (fgusecataccessrole IS NULL))
                   Rows Removed by Filter: 393
     Planning time: 0.474 ms
     Execution time: 27.183 ms
    (8 registros)
```

The query plan doesn't show the real time from the execution.

CREATE TABLE dcdocument

```
CREATE TABLE public.dcdocument
(
    cddocument integer NOT NULL,
    cdcategory integer,
    dtdocument date,
    fgstatus integer,
    dssummary text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nmtitle character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nmauthor character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    iddocument character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    dsdoccancel text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    fgusecataccessrole integer,
    cdcreatedby integer,
    nrhits integer,
    dtinsert date,
    dtupdate date,
    nmuserupd character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    dtvalidity date,
    qtvalidity integer,
    fgtypevalid integer,
    cdprod integer,
    cdapprov integer,
    cdtemparchival integer,
    cdfavorite integer,
    fgoldstatus integer,
    CONSTRAINT pkdcdocument PRIMARY KEY (cddocument),
    CONSTRAINT fkdocumcdcreatedby FOREIGN KEY (cdcreatedby)
        REFERENCES public.aduser (cduser) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.dcdocument
    OWNER to postgres;
CREATE INDEX "TESTES"
    ON public.dcdocument USING btree
    (cddocument, fgusecataccessrole)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixdoccataccessrole
    ON public.dcdocument USING btree
    (fgusecataccessrole)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixdoccdcategory
    ON public.dcdocument USING btree
    (cdcategory)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixdocumcdcreated
    ON public.dcdocument USING btree
    (cdcreatedby)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixdocumentapprov
    ON public.dcdocument USING btree
    (cdprod, cdapprov)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixdocumentfavori
    ON public.dcdocument USING btree
    (cdfavorite)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixdocumentstatus
    ON public.dcdocument USING btree
    (fgstatus)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixdocumtemparchi
    ON public.dcdocument USING btree
    (cdtemparchival)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

CREATE TABLE aduser

```
CREATE TABLE public.aduser
(
    cduser integer NOT NULL,
    idlogin character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    iduser character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nmuser character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    idpassword character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    dsuseremail text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    fglanguage integer,
    fguserenabled integer,
    cdmailserver integer,
    cdleader integer,
    dtinsert date,
    dtupdate date,
    nmuserupd character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    idphone character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    dsuser text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nmdomainuid character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nmcertserialnum character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    flpublickey bytea,
    fgnotice integer,
    fgstatuslogin integer,
    flphoto bytea,
    fgaccessrestrict integer,
    fgalterpassword integer,
    nmviewmodules character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    idpasswordvalid character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nmuseremail character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    fgtheme integer,
    fghomepage integer,
    dsurlhomepage text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    cddashboard integer,
    cddashboardtab integer,
    fgdashdoshare integer,
    dtrequestrstpsw date,
    idhashpassword character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    cdlastlicense integer,
    fgpwdversion integer,
    cdcustomization integer,
    nmhashlastsession character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    fgtransfped integer,
    cdtransfpedto integer,
    fgcontactenable integer,
    fgcontactpopup integer,
    cdfavorite integer,
    fgedittoolbar integer,
    fgeditgrid integer,
    nmphotopath character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    dtbirthday date,
    CONSTRAINT pkaduser PRIMARY KEY (cduser),
    CONSTRAINT fk__aduser__cdtransf__56764864 FOREIGN KEY (cdtransfpedto)
        REFERENCES public.aduser (cduser) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_userleader FOREIGN KEY (cdleader)
        REFERENCES public.aduser (cduser) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
ALTER TABLE public.aduser
    OWNER to postgres;
CREATE INDEX "TESTE2"
    ON public.aduser USING btree
    (cduser)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixcdleader
    ON public.aduser USING btree
    (cdleader)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixusercdmailserv
    ON public.aduser USING btree
    (cdmailserver)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixusercdtransfpedto
    ON public.aduser USING btree
    (cdtransfpedto)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixuserenabled
    ON public.aduser USING btree
    (fguserenabled)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixuserfglanguage
    ON public.aduser USING btree
    (fglanguage)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixusergnfavorite
    ON public.aduser USING btree
    (cdfavorite)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixuseridlogin
    ON public.aduser USING btree
    (idlogin COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixusernmdomainuid
    ON public.aduser USING btree
    (nmdomainuid COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX seixusernmfgencdus
    ON public.aduser USING btree
    (nmuser COLLATE pg_catalog."default", iduser COLLATE pg_catalog."default", cduser, fguserenabled)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Comment: Create index for `FGUSECATACCESSROLE`  ?

Comment: I already have an index for this table and column.

Comment: Show us the create table statements. and size of both tables. How many rows are `<> 1` ?

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Thx for the help Juan, I edited the post with some extra info

Comment: What happen to explain plan if you remove `aduser` table?  Still doesnt use the index?

Comment: Follow the query plan.

explain analyze select dc.cddocument from dcdocument dc WHERE  (dc.FGUSECATACCESSROLE <> 1 OR dc.FGUSECATACCESSROLE IS NULL);
--
 Seq Scan on dcdocument dc  (cost=0.00..12.51 rows=210 width=4) (actual time=0.045..0.333 rows=208 loops=1)
   Filter: ((fgusecataccessrole <> 1) OR (fgusecataccessrole IS NULL))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 393
 Planning time: 0.655 ms
 Execution time: 0.375 ms
(5 registros)

Comment: What are the tables row count?

Comment: Hi, 601 from dcdocumento and 591 to aduser.

Comment: Check `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\data\postgresql.conf` file. For `shared_buffers` and `work_mem` parameter.

Comment: I did a test with two tables same size as your, with a single column each. The cross join to generate 120k rows also take 4 seconds. I dont think you can reduce that time much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is already executed optimally, and it is done in 27 milliseconds.

There are two things that might help to explain the problem you observe:

1. You perform a cross join between the two tables, because you have no `WHERE` condition that connects them, that is, every row in `aduser` is combined with every row in `dcdocument` that matches the condition.

   That leads to 208 * 591 = 122928 result rows, which is probably not what you want.
2. You must be using a client like pgAdmin that takes a very long time to display the many result rows returned from the query.

The solution is probably to add the missing condition in a `WHERE` or `JOIN` clause.

Comment: When analyze said `Rows Removed by Filter: 393` that is from the last result meaning from the `122928` rows?

Comment: No, only from `dcdocument`. The condition is so that no index can readonably help, but with a small table like that that is no problem.

Comment: Im not sure if #2 apply here, because explain analyze doesn't return the rows to display, and 122k still not that many so that execution of 27 seconds is too high. My guess is problems with slow hard drive or very low  `shared_buffers` or `work_mem` settings

Comment: I'm doing a lab in my notebook, the challenge is to reduce the maximum amount of time in the query execution.

I'm using PGadmin, would you have another tool that best manages this?

I made several joins, but it does not come to the result of the first query lines.

I will do other tests following your tips, thank you.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The query runs for 27 *milli*seconds, that is 0.027 seconds, and `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` clearly says `actual ... rows=122928`. So I think you are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @BrunoFarias I prefer `psql` to pgAdmin, not least because it handles large result sets better. Your first objective is to find a good join condition to match rows from the two tables, then all other problems will go away.

Comment: Yes, I missread that one. But Im not barking, just an honest mistake

Comment: Thanks for the help @JuanCarlosOropeza and @ LaurenzAlbe i change the join for the tables, the column CDUSER from aduser have a fk with the table DCDOCACCESSROLE then i make a join.

FROM DCDOCACCESSROLE DAR
JOIN DCDOCUMENT DC ON DAR.CDDOCUMENT = DC.CDDOCUMENT

The query runs in 0.8 seconds!